# NullReferenceException не обрабатывается исключение

Tags: c#

Пытаюсь разобрать `Json`, но иногда не встречается необходимый ключ и получаю исключение `NullReferenceException`

А попытка обработать исключение `NullReferenceException` игнорируется и всё равно в данном случае на 3 строке вылетает исключение `NullReferenceException`

Почему такое происходит ?

```
            try
            {
                JToken city = sub_obj.Value["info"]["city"]["name"];

                if (city != null)
                {
                    people.sity= ($"{city.ToString()}");
                }
            }
            catch (NullReferenceException)
            {

            }
```

Comment: А почему не десериализация? Создайте классы, если свойство может быть NULL, то и делайте его `Nullable`, будет десериализатор за вас все делать. Ну а сейчас вы страдаете ерундой, что, например будете делать, если будет не `info`, а `data` в названии, или любой другой ключ поменяется? Везде искать эту строку? Ну, такое себе, можете многое пропустить, а так был бы просто класс.

Comment: `игнорируется` не игнорируется,это студия при отладке вам останавливает код, потому что по умолчанию данный тип исключений останавливает код. Вы можете продолжить выполнение, нажав соответствующую кнопку на панели студии, приложение не упадет. Типы исключений для остановки отладки настраиваются вами.

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-how-to читать и разбираться как работает десерализация. Перестать использовать Newtonsoft.Json и удалить его из проекта, начать использовать встроенный System.Text.Json.

Comment: @aepot Понял, спасибо.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ спасибо, взгляну на десериализацию, просто обычно вытаскивал только то что нужно.

Comment: Ну так сделайте класс, который будет состоять из только нужных свойств, вас ведь не заставляют делать полную копию JSON)

Comment: @EvgeniyZ а как быть с построенным классом, если там не хватает свойств ? Дело в том, что Json приходит, то с большим, то с меньшим количеством ключей. И я возможно ещё не о всех существующих ключах пока знаю. Просто достраивать класс ?

Comment: Вам эти свойства нужны? Если да - допишите в класс, а где будете использовать сделайте проверку на null, если не нужны - забудьте. Можете выбрать не класс, а словарь (`Dictionary<string, ...>`), тогда уже будет идти работа со словарем, где просто проверяете наличие ключа и если есть - делаете нужную логику.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ ещё один вопросик, а как отлавливать заранее неизвестные свойства ?

Comment: @Vipz JSON - это строго структурированный формат, который описывает конкретные объекты, в нем не может (не должно) быть изменений в ходе работы проекта. Если у вас такое там есть, то либо сериализатор отсекает NULL свойства, убирая их из JSON, либо у вас там "коллекция". Если первое - без конкретной структуры класса сервера, вы не узнаете все свойства, отловить - вручную, ну или напишите нечто на подобии "если свойства нет в вашем классе, то записать этот файлик в JSON для дальнейшего анализа". Если второе - словарь в помощь, будет вам динамическая коллекция.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Там 1-е. Понял, спасибо!

Comment: @aepot что то немного уже привык к `Newtonsoft.Json` и если что то подзабыл, в поисках подсказок, все на `Newtonsoft.Json` разъясняют, спасибо, попробую встроенный System.Text.Json

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> попытка обработать исключение `NullReferenceException` игнорируется

Не игнорируется,это студия при отладке вам останавливает код, потому что по умолчанию данный тип исключений останавливает код. Вы можете продолжить выполнение, нажав соответствующую кнопку на панели студии, приложение не упадет.

Типы исключений для остановки отладки настраиваются вами: [документация Visual Studio](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/visualstudio/debugger/managing-exceptions-with-the-debugger).